# How to call Soap\WSDL Service through a login required webpage using matlab?

Tags: web-services, matlab, authentication

I am new to the wsdl\soapmessage query\reply world( if i can put it in this way), and I am facing some difficulties using the following wsdl( which I really really hope, one will be so kind to look at at least one of the services described there)
http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/ws/services/TrackerWebService?wsdl

which was provided to me to develop a matlab webinterface. Right now my matlab code looks like this:

```
targetNamespace = 'http://ws.polarion.com/TrackerWebService';

method = 'queryWorkItems';
values= {'Query','Sort'}
names = {'query', 'sort'}
types ={'xsd:string','xsd:string'}
message = createSoapMessage( targetNamespace, method, values, names, types)


response = callSoapService('http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/ws/services',...
% Service's endpoint
'http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/#/workitems',...
% Server method to run
message)
% SOAP message created using createSoapMessage

author = parseSoapResponse(response)
```

Herewith to save you time I will just enonce my two problems:

1. Is the code correct?
2. Could someone tell me if such a wsdl link is just a definition of webservices or it is also a service's endpoint?
3. Normally to execute manually\per clicks this services on the weppage
   http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion, you have to login!

So how do I send a message in matlab which first log me in? Or must such a service be introduced into that wsdl for me to do it?? Could you be kind enough to write how it must be defined, because I don't really 
write wsdl files, but I shall learn!**

I will be really thankful for your help and I wish you a happy week(-end) guys(& girls)!!!

Regards

Chrysmac

ps: I tried to use Soapui and gave that webpage as endpoint, but the toool crashes each time I enter my credentials! Maybe because of the dataload!??

Comment: it is also possible I must use createClassFromWsdl instead like this:"
xmlout = urlread2( 'http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/ws/services/TrackerWebService?wsdl', 'GET', [], []);


createClassFromWsdl('http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/ws/services/TrackerWebService?wsdl')

Comment: But then I get errors from matlab. like the wsdl structure is not correct!

Comment: You'll probably need to specify the credentials in your call to the service.